# Would WebGL be a good prototype for code that will work on the Android platform

Tags: android, opengl-es, webgl

I am going to start on my first graphics program on the Android(http://blog.jayway.com/2009/12/03/opengl-es-tutorial-for-android-part-i/), but it would seem faster to use use javascript, and so use `WebGL` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL) to prototype the graphical part of the game.

One difference is in how textures are done, I expect, but for the main part of the game, which is this case is something similar to Tetris, in that you try to pack various shapes into a container optimally.

I would like to prototype it in javascript, but if it will be work to get it to work on the Android then it may not be worth it, hence my question as to how similar is OpenGL on these two platforms?

Answer (score 1):

both use the OpenGL ES 2.0 version. Still, for ease of use, some things are adapted for javascript (webgl). But if you worry about how different the "OpenGL Versions are" the answer is, you don't really need to worry.

Answer (score 1):

I've started a Tetris WebGL application here, tested in Firefox Fennec, but still many more items to get done. http://phillihp.com/projects/creating-tetris-with-opengl-and-webgl/

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is a question of taste. No doubt webgl shaders compatible with androids shaders as good as webgl shader written for one desktop compatible with mac or visa verse. Always little caveats, but not a big deal to overcome them. Moreover you can make Android application from HTML application and ship it to end user. It is possible.